# Is it possible to add date filters in SPSiteDataQuery in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to query SharePoint data from multiple lists. So I am using SPSiteDataQuery using list template ID. Here I need to filter the results based on the dates which is passed as function parameters instead of querying the entire data. Is it possible to add date filters in SPSiteDataQuery?

I have tried to get the data without filters and it is working in dev environment. However in pre-production environment I am getting threshold error. I have the same data in dev and pre-production environment. Following is the error:
{"Exception":{"Message":"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleThrottleException(COMException comEx)\u000d\u000a   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CrossListQuery(String bstrUrl, String bstrXmlWebs, String bstrXmlLists, String bstrXmlQuery, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pCallback, Object& pvarColumns)\u000d\u000a   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetSiteData(SPSiteDataQuery query)\u000d\u000a

```
                        var query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                        query.Query = "";

                        query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"108\" />";
                        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                                          "<FieldRef Name=\"Country\" />";
                        query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
                        query.RowLimit = 500000;
                        DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve issue with large lists set SPSiteDataQuery.SPQueryThrottleOption to Override before executing query and also open SPWeb as System Account using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.